# Formula for standardized root mean square residual (SRMR) in longitudinal latent variable models (SEM, CFA)

Tags: goodness-of-fit, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, confirmatory-factor

First note, related: [What is the formula for Standardized Root Mean Residual (SRMR) in the context of latent variable models (e.g., SEM, CFA)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235872/what-is-the-formula-for-standardized-root-mean-residual-srmr-in-the-context-of)

I was wondering what the adaption to the formula should be in case of multiple groups or longitudinal data (i.e. several time points).

[image]

[image]

As provided in the related / linked question, source: Hu, L.; Bentler, Peter (1999). "Cutoff criteria for fit indexes in covariance structure analysis: Conventional criteria versus new alternatives". Structural Equation Modeling. 6 (1): 1–55. https://dx.doi.org/10.1080%2F10705519909540118

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the multi group SEM, the SRMR is calculated by using a weighted average under the square root where each sample covariance matrix is compared to the model predicted covariance matrix.  I did not locate a reference, but I did run a quick multi-group SEM, and then calculated the single group SEMs and confirmed this formula to be correct.

**Requested Addition**
Demonstration for calculating SRMR for two groups:
$$SRMR = \sqrt{\frac{n_1·SRMR_1^2 + n_2·SRMR_2^2}{n_1+n_2}}$$
where $n_i$ and $SRMR_i$ are the sample size and $SRMR$ of group $i$, respectively. (Worked example in comments below.)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Although I understand the idea of a 'weighted average', I am not really good at translating this into a formula. My background involves few mathematical courses. Would you mind illustrating the formula?

Comment: If you have two groups, $n_1 = 200$, $SRMR_1 = 0.04$, $n_2 = 500$, $SRMR_2 = 0.02$, then $SRMR = \sqrt{\frac{n_1SRMR_1^2 + n_2SRMR_2^2}{n_1+n_2}}=\sqrt{\frac{200·(0.04)^2 + 500·(0.02)^2}{200+400}} = \sqrt{\frac{0.52}{700}} = .0273$.

Comment: Much appreciated, 100% clear now. Perhaps you could copy / paste this into your answer. Then I'll accept it as an answer, so other ppl will benefit from this as well :)

Comment: Happy to do so.

Comment: Hi Gregg, I recently returned to this topic and compared the results of 4 cross-sectional CFA models (1 time point each), to a longitudinal CFA model with the 4 time points jointly. I did this in Lavaan and computed the 4 SRMRs separately and then used the formula you illustrated above (the sample sizes slightly differ due to complete case analysis where the number of missing data points differs per time point). Then I compared this number to the SRMR calculated by Lavaan based on the longitudinal model. However, the numbers are rather different: 0.06921215 vs 0.085. Any suggestions why?

Comment: It seems, but I am not sure if I am correct, that I cannot extend the formula like that. In the longitudinal case, the SRMR is based on covariance matrices of k*T by k*T, where k is the number of items and T the number of time periods (e.g., 4*5 by 4*5 if we have 4 items and 5 time periods). In the cross sectional case, the SRMRs are based on k by k matrices (e.g., 4 by 4), where correlations between time points are ignored.

Comment: I believe the issue you suggest in the 2nd comment is correct...the longitudinal model would include all of the cross-temporal point correlations (i.e., the correlation of time $i$ with time $j$, $i \ne j$.